# Efficient way to add/remove multiple records in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to add/remove multiple records from kendo grid. As my grid contains a check box in each row for multi-select functionality I am handling record selection in a custom way so as to check the checkbox on grid row selection, Now the problem I am facing is to add multiple records at a time when iterating over records. This is causing performance issues. Following is a code snippet. In the below code 'copySelectedToRemainingExtensionsGrid' and 'copySelectedToIncludedExtensionsGrid' are button ids and 'includedExtensionsGrid', '#remainingExtensionsGrid' are kendo grid ID's.

```
//Here I am creating button click events for moving records from one grid to another
    jQuery("#copySelectedToRemainingExtensionsGrid").on("click", function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              moveTo("#includedExtensionsGrid", "#remainingExtensionsGrid");
          });

//Here I am creating button click events for moving records from one grid to another    
          jQuery("#copySelectedToIncludedExtensionsGrid").on("click", function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              moveTo("#remainingExtensionsGrid", "#includedExtensionsGrid");
          });

//This method contains actual code for moving data from one grid to another
          function moveTo(from, to) {

        var fromGrid = jQuery(from).data("kendoGrid");
        var items = [];
        jQuery(from+" .k-grid-content tbody .k-state-selected").each(function () {
            items.push(fromGrid.dataItem(this));
        });

        var fromDS = fromGrid.dataSource;
        var toDS = jQuery(to).data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        jQuery.each(items, function (idx, elem) {
              toDS.add({ id: elem.id, name: elem.name});
              fromDS.remove(elem);
        });

        checkGridHeaderCheckbox('#includedExtensionsGrid');
        checkGridHeaderCheckbox('#remainingExtensionsGrid');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get all the data you want to move then you can use `dataSource.pushCreate()` and `dataSource.pushDestroy()` for further read here is a [link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-pushCreate). Those method can add/delete single or multiple item to kendo datasource, for single :

```
dataSource.pushCreate({ id: 1, name: "John Doe" });
```

and for multiple :

```
dataSource.pushCreate([
    { id: 1, name: "John Doe" },
    { id: 2, name: "Jane Doe" }
]);
```